# If the Gibbs Sampler assumes knowledge of full conditionals -- why can't we just solve for the full joint density and avoid Gibbs?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

Suppose that $y_1, y_2$ are data drawn from a density function $f$ with parameters $\theta_1, \theta_2$ which are unknown. Suppose I applied some prior on $\theta_1, \theta_2$. Then, the Gibbs sampler states that if we know the FULL conditional distributions:

$$
p(\theta_1|\theta_2, y) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ p(\theta_2|\theta_1, y)
$$

then we may draw from each and be able to approximate draws from the joint distribution $p(\theta_1, \theta_2)$, which is assumed to be hard to find (which is why we do Gibbs here to begin with).

We may rewrite the above as:

$$
p(\theta_1|\theta_2, y) = \frac{p(\theta_1,\theta_2, y)}{p(\theta_2, y)} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ p(\theta_2|\theta_1, y) = \frac{p(\theta_2,\theta_1, y)}{p(\theta_1, y)}
$$

Now, I assume that we know $p(\theta_1, y)$ and $p(\theta_2, y)$ from the prior specification. Then, if we know $p(\theta_1, y)$ and $p(\theta_1|\theta_2, y)$, don't we also know $p(\theta_1,\theta_2, y)$?

What exactly is the Gibb's sampler doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematically, this is correct: once you know
$$p(\theta_1|\theta_2, y) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ p(\theta_2|\theta_1, y)$$
you can derive the joint posterior distribution as
$$p(\theta_1,\theta_2|y) = \dfrac{p(\theta_1|\theta_2,y)}{\int p(\theta_1|\theta_2,y)\big/p(\theta_2|\theta_1, y)\,\text{d}\theta_1}$$
[This is Theorem 9.3 in [our book](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR).]

However the reason for running Gibbs sampling is that/when this expression is not available in closed form and hence cannot be simulated directly. In the event one knows $p(\theta_1,y)$ or $p(\theta_2,y)$ in closed form *and* can simulate $\theta_1$ or $\theta_2$ from the former or the latter, resp., then one does not require Gibbs sampling as direct simulation becomes feasible.

Comment: So you're basically saying that even if I can compute $p(\theta_1,\theta_2, y)$ from the full conditionals, to get to $p(\theta_1,\theta_2|y)$, I still need the $p(y)$ on the denominator, which is the normalizing constant and hence  whose closed form is the deciding factor in whether to use Gibbs or not?

Comment: I see, so $\int p(\theta_1|\theta_2,y)\big/p(\theta_2|\theta_1, y)\,\text{d}\theta_1 = \frac{1}{p(\theta_2,y)}\int p(\theta_1, y)d\theta_1 = \frac{p(y)}{p(\theta_2,y)}$. For the closed form and simulation requirement, is to facilitate the calculation of the integral part $\int p(\theta_1, y)d\theta_1$ or the fraction part $\frac{1}{p(\theta_2,y)}$? Thank you!

Comment: Gibbs sampling does not aim at recovering the joint density, only at simulating from this density.

Comment: When you say **"However the reason for running Gibbs sampling is that/when this expression is not available in closed form and hence cannot be simulated directly."**, when is it NOT available in closed form? Is it when you cannot evaluate the integral in the denominator above?

Comment: @user321627: when the integral is not available in closed form or when it involves an expression complicated enough to prevent simulating from this distribution, conditionals need be used instead.